# mongo db is not creating super user on centOS 7?

Tags: database, mongodb, centos7

I have installed mongodb on centOS 7. I can access the mongodb with command mongo here are my shell commands:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.19
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2018-02-27T06:49:14.392+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-27T06:49:14.393+0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.

> use admin;
switched to db admin

> db.createUser( { user: "tr1", pwd: "123123", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase" ] } );
2018-02-27T07:06:29.833+0500 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: No role named userAdminAnyDatabase@qsu_mweb_institution_1 :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1267:15
@(shell):1:1
```

When I try to create a user with some admin role it is giving strange error.

Can anybody help what is wrong ? I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reinstall mongodb with:

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

It will update missing things. Then try